# Was vertritt das Pronomen "es" in diesem Fall?

Tags: pronoun

> Gemacht habe ich es gestern schon.

Im oberen gezeigten Fall, steht das Pronomen "es" für das Partizip II "gemacht", oder steht es für einen Komplement der vorher erwähnt worden wäre?

Ich habe die gleiche Frage für den folgenden Fall:

> Essen würde ich es lieber nicht.

Geht "es" hier um den eigenen Tat vom Essen, oder  um ein Lebensmittel?

Comment: **To close voters:** Please do not vote to close as "unclear" without asking for clarification. That is what comments are for - they are not for giving answers.

Comment: If I make a question it's because the point is unclear for me. Otherwise I wouldn't post it. I deeply contempt the close voters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Das Schnitzel** ist schon ganz grün. Essen würde ich **es** lieber nicht.

*Es* ist hier ein Rückgriff auf ein zuvor erwähntes Subjekt/Objekt.

> **Hast** du **den Schuppen aufgeräumt**? – Gemacht habe ich **es** gestern schon.
>
> Was hast du gestern schon gemacht? – (Ich habe) den Schuppen aufgeräumt.

*Es* ist hier ein Rückgriff auf fast den gesamten vorigen Satz.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde in beiden Fällen ein 'das' dem 'es' vorziehen. Beide Sätze haben eine ungewöhnliche Wortstellung, bei der ein Satzteil durch Voranstellung (und gesprochen-sprachlich zusätzlich durch Betonung) hervorgehoben wird, der normalerweise weiter hinten im Satz zu stehen käme. Beide beziehen sich auf vorangehende Äußerungen, mir kommen sie wie Teile eines Dialogs vor. Wenn das so gedacht sein sollte, dann wäre in meiner Region - Ruhrgebiet - jedenfalls der Satz mit *'Gemacht ...'* einem Dialog unter leicht überkandidelten Herrschaften entnommen, Typ Kulturschickeria alter Schule. Die Normalversion des ersten Beispiels wäre bei uns *'ich hab das gestern bereits erledigt.'* Mir fällt kein Kontext ein, in dem der Satz in der Ursprungsversion gesagt werden könnte, und zwar wegen des betonten *'gemacht'*, denn so ein Satz müsste mit einem *'aber'* oder *'nur/allerdings'* fortgesetzt werden können. So etwas ließe sich jedoch nur mit einem anderen Verb und damit mit einer anderen Aussage bewerkstelligen, z.B. so: *'Abgeschrieben habe ich das gestern schon, nur auswendig gelernt habe ich es noch nicht.'* Wohl niemand würde auf eine Aufforderung wie *'... und mach dein Bett, bevor du aus dem Haus gehst'* antworten mit: *'Gemacht habe ich es/das gestern schon.'* Oder gibt's doch einen passenden Kontext, der mir nur nicht einfällt?

Das Beispiel mit dem Schnitzel hingegen kann ich mir auch in der Realität gut vorstellen.